# Textbox entry giving errors

Tags: c#

I have 4 text boxes.
In first textbox just i am doubleclicking and opening child form.
There I am displaying some names and values.
I am selecting one name in that form and that name is coming to first form first text box and next text box value is coming.
Next I want to take input using third text box and do some caliculations, display result in fourth textbox(readonly one).
But it is giving some error.
What I made mistake.

```
//Take values from child form:
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{   
    Form8.code = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();   
    Form8.name = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    Form8.fiel= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
    Form8.measure= dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

    //my main form to store that values:
    boxname.Text = name;
    if (boxname.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Empty Name");
    }
    else
    {
        boxbprice.Text = fiel;
        double qty = Convert.ToDouble(boxqty.Text);//taking quanty input
    }
```

Where I did mistake. It is giving some error

> "input String was not in a currect format"

Comment: You say `Convert.ToDouble(boxqty.Text);`, its saying you did not input a correct double

Comment: What is the value of `boxqty.Text` when you're debugging? Are you sure it is valid text representation of a double value (in the correct format)?

Comment: @ bassfader that boxqty.Text is a text box for taking input.

Comment: @vijay You don't seem to understand what anyone is saying. Hes not asking what it is, its obviously a TextBox but hes asking what its value is when you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "input String was not in a currect format"

The error means that the `string` which you're trying to parse doesn't actually contain a double value.

- ensure the field which holds the input data is a valid text representation of a `double` value (in the correct format).
- you could use [**`Double.TryParse`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent the error, however you'd need to debug the program and see the actual value of `Convert.ToDouble(boxqty.Text);` at run time.

---

**Example of using TryParse:**

```
double number;
if (Double.TryParse(boxqty.Text, out number)){
  // do something with the value of number
}
```

Comment: @ ousmane It is working but before I entered some value control is going so Empty

Answer (score 0):

Its saying your boxqty.Text is not in a valid double format, if you want to use a different format (eg. `,` as separator) you can use a custom format provider.

**Example:**

```
NumberFormatInfo provider = new NumberFormatInfo();
provider.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

string doubleString = "125,231";
double actualDouble = Convert.ToDouble( doubleString, provider );
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s9ak971(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Note**
This will still throw an error if the format is still not correct. *Thanks bassfader

Comment: Though keep in mind that this will still throw an exception on any other invalid input. So I'd suggest to use [`double.TryParse()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) instead (it also has an overload allowing to provide a different `IFormatProvider` to support different number formats)

Comment: @bassfader Lets keep it easy shall we, he does not even know why he's getting an error. I do agree with you though :)

Comment: @ Epickip textboxes all by default strings only na.thats why i am simply cinverting that to double. in that form only i am facing this error. other forms are there same tyrp of convertions i did. but no prob. maybe i am taking values from child form is the cause?

Comment: @vijay No if the error occurred in the part of code you posted in can only come from the conversion which uses the textbox text so no child form value or anything

Comment: @vijay Maybe debug and see what value its trying to convert? No one knows the actual reason of your error until they know input

Comment: @ epic this same method i am using for a datagridview entry  but there it is coming in text boxes only I am getting errors. there also i used same child form sames values.

Comment: @vijay You don't seem to understand me, if its giving an error now you are clearly not using the same values.... for the last time DEBUG and you can see what the value of `boxqty.Text` is

Comment: I did. It is null value. But i am unable to input into that textbox  also because of this error

Comment: ... the `Text` property of a WinForms `TextBox` does never return `null` (though an empty string could be possible if you didn't enter anything in the box)...

Comment: @bassfader I'd almost add a 'how to debug' link, this is rediculous